How to draw a toroidal graph?
Following MichaelE2's advice, I completely revised my question. The original form of my question follows for the sake of contributed answers.
I have a following toroidal graph
g=Graph[List[1<->2,3<->4,5<->6,7<->8,9<->10,11<->12,13<->14,15<->16,17<->18,19<->20,21<->22,23<->24,25<->26,27<->28,29<->30,31<->32,33<->34,35<->36,37<->38,39<->40,41<->42,43<->44,45<->46,47<->48,49<->50,51<->52,53<->54,55<->56,57<->58,59<->60,61<->62,63<->64,65<->66,67<->68,69<->70,71<->72,73<->74,75<->76,77<->78,79<->80,81<->82,83<->84,85<->86,87<->88,89<->90,91<->92,93<->94,95<->96,97<->98,99<->100,101<->102,103<->104,105<->106,107<->108,109<->110,111<->112,113<->114,115<->116,117<->118,119<->120,3<->8,5<->14,1<->20,11<->2,7<->16,9<->22,15<->4,17<->10,13<->24,23<->6,19<->12,21<->18,27<->32,29<->38,25<->44,35<->26,31<->40,33<->46,39<->28,41<->34,37<->48,47<->30,43<->36,45<->42,51<->56,53<->62,49<->68,59<->50,55<->64,57<->70,63<->52,65<->58,61<->72,71<->54,67<->60,69<->66,75<->80,77<->86,73<->92,83<->74,79<->88,81<->94,87<->76,89<->82,85<->96,95<->78,91<->84,93<->90,99<->104,101<->110,97<->116,107<->98,103<->112,105<->118,111<->100,113<->106,109<->120,119<->102,115<->108,117<->114,1<->32,3<->44,5<->38,7<->50,9<->70,11<->64,13<->78,15<->84,17<->90,19<->100,21<->106,23<->120,25<->8,27<->20,29<->14,31<->102,33<->114,35<->108,37<->76,39<->96,41<->82,43<->58,45<->72,47<->52,49<->116,51<->110,53<->104,55<->2,57<->22,59<->16,61<->42,63<->30,65<->36,67<->88,69<->74,71<->94,73<->118,75<->98,77<->112,79<->60,81<->54,83<->66,85<->28,87<->48,89<->34,91<->4,93<->10,95<->24,97<->68,99<->62,101<->56,103<->86,105<->92,107<->80,109<->6,111<->12,113<->18,115<->26,117<->46,119<->40]];

Topologically, the torus $T^2$ is obtained from a rectangle $R$ as a fundamental domain by identifying the opposite sides. So, I want to draw the graph $g$ as embedded in $R$ so that the toroidality of $g$ is manifest. How should this be done?
There are infinitely many such embeddings, but just a single instance is fine for me.
Original question
A combinatorial graph G is called toroidal if G can be drawn (in principle) on a torus without edge crossing.
For example, the following non-planar graph
gr = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 
    5 <-> 6, 4 <-> 7, 5 <-> 8, 7 <-> 8, 
    6 <-> 9, 7 <-> 10, 8 <-> 11, 9 <-> 12, 
    11 <-> 12, 10 <-> 13, 11 <-> 14, 13 <-> 14, 
    12 <-> 15, 13 <-> 16, 14 <-> 17, 15 <-> 18, 
    17 <-> 18, 16 <-> 19, 17 <-> 20, 19 <-> 20, 
    18 <-> 21, 20 <-> 22, 21 <-> 23, 22 <-> 23, 
    23 <-> 24, 24 <-> 6, 24 <-> 16, 21 <-> 10, 
    15 <-> 4, 9 <-> 1, 22 <-> 3, 19 <-> 1}];

is toroidal. This can be easily seen from the following picture:
Graph[gr,VertexCoordinates->{{2.31`,2.`},{3.46`,3.`},{2.31`,5.`},{5.77`,2.`},{3.46`,6.`},{2.31`,8.`},{6.93`,3.`},{5.77`,5.`},{3.46`,9.`},{9.24`,2.`},{6.93`,6.`},{5.77`,8.`},{10.39`,3.`},{9.24`,5.`},{6.93`,9.`},{12.7`,2.`},{10.39`,6.`},{9.24`,8.`},{13.86`,3.`},{12.7`,5.`},{10.39`,9.`},{13.86`,6.`},{12.7`,8.`},{13.86`,9.`}},EdgeStyle->(#->Dashed&/@{1<->9,4<->15,10<->21,16<->24,6<->24,3<->22,1<->19})]


Dashed edges go all the way along the nontrivial cycles of the torus.
BUT I had to not only set VertexCoordinates manually but also choose carefully which edges are making detour.
My question is: Given a more general toroidal graph (without embedding), is it possible to find automatically such a vertex-embedding and a set of detour-edges?
Ideally speaking, I want a picture like this:


I suggest you first look into mathematical aspects of this. It's called a toroidal graph.

@Domen Thank you very much for the comment. I looked into graph theory on surfaces, but I haven't came across that word. I'll edit my question.

One way: If "Given a toroidal graph" does not mean that we are given a toroidal embedding, then take your favorite torus-embedding algorithm, embed the graph, pull back to the domain of a standard parametrization of a torus if the algorithm doesn't do this already. I don't think Mathematica has a toroidal, neither built-in nor via a resource function. Not sure about igraph, but I couldn't find one through google.

Looks relevant: A Faster Algorithm for Torus Embedding.

TorusGraph can be used to create various test cases.

@MichaelE2 Thank you for your comment. Yes, "a toroidal graph" is given without toroidal embedding. I searched for graph embedding algorithms but almost all are about planar embedding. Maybe I should search much harder...

@Domen Thank you very much. The paper seems to provide a nice solution! I am thinking of variational approach using doubly periodic functions as a potential between vertices, but before trying this, I asked SE whether good solution is already known.

@GregHurst Thank you for telling me about TorusGraph. I have only a couple of toric graphs, so the command is really helpful to create many other examples.

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C11&q=torus+embeddings+graphs&btnG= gives a fairly decent density of useful-looking hits, including the paper @Domen linked. I'm afraid you might have to code an algorithm yourself. If you succeed, it might be worth adding to the resource function repository.

Suppose you install the IGraphM:
Needs["IGraphM`"]

You can get a graph like flowwing:
graph = IGMeshGraph@IGLatticeMesh["Hexagonal", {6, 4}]


Then transform its coordinates:
Graph[graph, 
 VertexCoordinates -> 
  Thread[VertexList[graph] -> 
    ShearingTransform[-30 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}][
     GraphEmbedding[graph]]]]



Thank you for your answer. I want a method which works not only for the graph given above but also for general toroidal graphs.

A long comment/example: The focus on a tiling coming from the sole example in the OP seems misleading. (At least I feel the point is being missed.)  Here is another example with a few toroidal embeddings, done ad hoc & by hand, just to give different type of example that needs to be dealt with.
g = CompleteGraph[5];

Graph[g, 
 EdgeStyle -> (# -> Dashed & /@ 
    DeleteCases[EdgeList[g], _[i_, j_] /; j - i == 1])]

toroidal = Graph[g, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Table[{k/6., 0.05 + 0.9 Sin[Pi (k - 1)/4.]}, {k, 5}], 
   EdgeStyle -> (# -> Dashed & /@ 
      DeleteCases[EdgeList[g], _[i_, j_] /; j - i == 1])];
Show[
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Rectangle[]}],
 toroidal
 ]



A 3rd, with an explicit toroidal embedding:
coords3 = Table[{k/5. - 1/10, 0.5}, {k, 5}];
tor3 =
  Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> coords3, 
   EdgeStyle -> (# -> Dashed & /@ 
      DeleteCases[EdgeList[g], _[i_, j_] /; j - i == 1])];

toroidalParametrization[u_, 
   v_] := {(2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[2 Pi u], (2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[
     2 Pi u], Sin[2 Pi v]};

edgeParametrization[coords_, _[1, 5], 
   t_] := (1 - t) (coords[[1]] + {1, 0}) + t coords[[5]];
edgeParametrization[coords_, _[i_, j_], t_] /; 
   j - i == 1 := (1 - t) (coords[[i]]) + t coords[[j]];
edgeParametrization[coords_, _[i_, j_], t_] /; 
   j - i == 3 := (1 - t) (coords[[i]] + {1, -1}) + t coords[[j]];
edgeParametrization[coords_, _[i_, j_], 
   t_] := (1 - t) (coords[[i]] + {0, 1}) + t coords[[j]];

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[toroidalParametrization[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1], Mesh -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thin]],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[
   toroidalParametrization @@ edgeParametrization[coords3, #, t] & /@ 
    EdgeList[g]],
  {t, 0, 1}],
 Graphics3D[
  Sphere[#, 0.1] & /@ toroidalParametrization @@@ coords3
  ]
 ]



The default display of tor3 has the edges overlapping on a line. I'm not sure that the OP's requirement that edges that cross the boundary of a fundamental domain should be drawn dashed but within the domain will result in the best visualizations.

Thank you for clarifying discussion. I completely revised my question.


Maybe similar with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/302957/72111

Clear["Global`*"];
e = {e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6} = CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 6];
L = 50;
original = {0, 0};
r = Sqrt[3]/12;
scale = .8;
λ = 0;
(*λ=0.012;*)
pts0 = Flatten[
   Table[original + scale*r    {i, j} . {e1, e2} + 
     RandomReal[{0, λ}, 2], {i, -L, L}, {j, -L, L}], 1];
pts = Select[pts0, RegionMember[Rectangle[], #] &];
ptss = TranslationTransform[#][pts] & /@ Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, 2];
pts2 = Flatten[ptss, 1];
vor = VoronoiMesh[pts2, {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}, Frame -> True, 
   Epilog -> Point@pts];
(*HighlightMesh[vor,Catenate@NearestMeshCells[{vor,2},#]&/@pts]*)
vcells = Catenate[NearestMeshCells[{vor, 2}, #] & /@ pts];
pvor = MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[vor], MeshCells[vor, vcells], 
   MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black, 2 -> Pink}, 
   Epilog -> {Black, Point@pts}];
graph = MeshConnectivityGraph[pvor]
Graph[graph, 
 VertexCoordinates -> 
  ShearingTransform[30   Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]@
   GraphEmbedding[graph], VertexSize -> .5]


